# How can I center the map on my own position?

Tags: swift, xcode

On a xcode application, I display many pins from my database and my position but the map is not centered on my position

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Create coordinates from location lat/long
    var poiCoodinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    tab = selectedEtablissement as! [EtablissementModel]

    for item in 0..<tab.count{

        poiCoodinates.latitude = tab[item].lonetablissement!
        poiCoodinates.longitude = tab[item].lngetablissement!

        // Zoom to region
        let viewRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: poiCoodinates, latitudinalMeters: 750, longitudinalMeters: 750)

        self.mapB******.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
        // Plot pin
        let pin: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin.coordinate = poiCoodinates
        self.mapB*******.addAnnotation(pin)

        //add title to the pin
        pin.title = tab[item].nometablissement
    }

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    mapBieres.showsUserLocation = true
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

The pins are displayed on many cities and with this code, my position is displayed but the map is not centered on my position. I want all the pins on the map but the map centered on my position. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
`import MapKit
 import CoreLocation

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


  func setLocation() { // Seeting up current location
        locationManager.delegate = self as CLLocationManagerDelegate
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
   // Setting the current location to the ashton building, & the zoom of the map
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locationOfUser = locations[0]
        let lat = locationOfUser.coordinate.latitude
        let long = locationOfUser.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.003 // Distance from the map
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.003
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}`
```

The following code should help you set up your current location, as well as the distance zoom of the map. (make sure current location is turned on in settings, if I remember correctly).
    Hope this can help in anyway, had to look through my old Swift assignments:)

Comment: It's run. Thank you